# Getting time gap between a datetime field and NOW() in MySQL

Tags: mysql, cron

I have a database that has a users table.  Within the table are two fields:  a datetime field for when users initially register with a website, and another datetime field for when that registration has been confirmed by the user via e-mail.

I'm expecting a lot of people to register but never activate their accounts, and I don't want to bog down my table with non-users, so I am creating a CRON script.  The script will run every 24 hours, and will delete the rows where the user has registered but hasn't activated account after x number of days.  the pseudo-code would look something like this:

```
DELETE FROM users WHERE [registration_date is more than 72 hours after NOW() ] AND ISNULL(registration_confirmed)
```

As I said that's the pseudo-code; I am not sure how to get the time gap between a datetime field and NOW().  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

```
WHERE registration_date < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 72 HOUR
AND registration_confirmed IS NULL
```